Not sure if im getting fired
I started a job last September. I had issues with getting good help. The second shift person and I butt heads we had meeting in January where she lied and nothing happened. Well it started again late June. Managers, supervisors wanted her to do her job I didn't tell on her but she's been making my life unbearable at work when confronted by management believing I was the person who told. I finally stated to management this hostile behavior they want a meeting I didn't want the meeting told them no in email and several times verbally.I wanted who ever told them about her behavior in the meeting but they forced me and I screamed and was in her face I lost my cool at being called a liar. Now I'm aggressive and HR is being informed of my loud argument and getting in co worker face. Do I have any recourse? I'm human she started name calling I'm at my wits end here.

Why would you say "no" at a request for a meeting from management or HR?  That alone seems like an offense that could get one fired.

HR get involved because they want to avoid a situation developing that could impact the business. Your refusal to engage with HR means they really have few other options other than fire you.

VTC - the only person who can answer whether or not you are getting fired is your management team.

You probably lost the battle when you let her get you riled up. NEVER raise your voice at work unless there is an immediate danger to life, health, or the survival of the business -- and that last is questionable.
All you can do now is try to explain what happened, calmly, emphasizing that you understand your mistake and that it won't happen again.
Then, if you can retain your job, you can work on clearly documenting the other person's behavior -- preferably getting witnesses, so lying can't become an issue-- and calmly take that evidence to management.
If they ask for a face-to-face with both of you, again, stay calm. "I'm sorry, but that isn't  true; here are logged instances and witnesses."
Note: I'm accepting for the sake of discussion that you did nothing to provoke the situation. But in my experience there is usually some blame on both sides. Think long and hard about whether any of the criticism might have been legitimate and intended to be helpful, before things got out of control.
